# What to do to remove None

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print the ODD numbers between 2 numbers(the numbers included).

for example: input: (2,9)

output: 3, 5, 7, 9

```
def  oddNumbers(l, r):
    if(l % 2 == 0):
        l = l + 1
        if(r %2 == 0):
            r = r-1
            while(l<=r):
                print (l)
                l = l+2
        else:
            while(l<=r):
                print (l)
                l = l+2
    else:
        if(r %2 == 0):
            r = r - 1
            while(l<=r):
                print (l)
                l = l+2
        else:
            while(l<=r):
                print (l)
                l = l+2

a = oddNumbers(2,8)
print(a)`
```

The above code gives the following output: `3 5 7 None`. I would like to now why am I getting that `None` and how do I remove it?

Comment: Why make it so complicated? `[i for i in range(low, high+1) if i % 2]`

Comment: Your function returns `None`. You assign that result to `a`. Then you print `a`. Just don't print `a` and you won't see the `None`.